# Почему scandir() не возвращает некоторые каталоги?

Tags: php

Кто нибудь сталкивался с проблемой, когда `scandir()` возвращает не всё содержимое каталога? В моем случае в каталоге находится *25 000* директорий, но `scandir()` возвращает *10 590*. Права у каталогов одинаковые, они не скрыты, через FileZilla свободно открываются. В чем может быть проблема?

```
$partnumbers = scandir($pathdir);
var_dump(count($partnumbers));die;
```

Comment: Возможно влияет время выполнение скрита

Comment: Какая ОС? Не включен ли SELinux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPD 2

Проверьте включен ли [SELinux](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux), скорее всего он ограничивает. Он даже рута может ограничивать. Админ на работе говорит, что он всегда выключает SELinux полностью.

Возможно есть какие то лимиты. Вообще это не очень хорошо, иметь такое количество каталогов в одной директории. Проверьте еще раз права, скорее всего проблема все таки в них.

В PHP лучше использовать [итераторы](http://php.net/manual/ru/spl.iterators.php), они с большим кол-вом циклов должны работать быстрее процедурки. Например:

```
$path = realpath('/etc');
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($objects as $name => $object){
    echo "$name\n";
}
```

### UPD

Еще можно использовать генераторы, они кстати вроде как быстрее чем итераторы даже:

```
function getAllFiles($dirName) {
    $dh  = opendir($dirName);
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($dh))) {
        yield $fileName;
    }
    closedir($dh);
}

foreach (getAllFiles('/etc') as $fileName) {
    echo "$fileName\n";
}
```

### Апрув по скорости работы

Тест на 70 тыс. файлов по 1Кб и 40 тыс. директорий в одном каталоге.

[scandir()](http://joxi.ru/823ja7jHKEYkmO), [yield](http://joxi.ru/p27LnqLiEQkPA7), [DirectoryIterator](http://joxi.ru/BA04Lk4iw0YGAy)

[scandir()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.scandir.php) жрет оперативку, это и понятно, место для массива с данными то хранить надо. [Генераторы](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.generators.overview.php) скорости не прибавили, печаль. А вот итератор [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.directoryiterator.php) выиграл и по скорости и по потреблению оперативки.

"На спичках" конечно, но при очень больших объемах думаю будет заметно.

Comment: DirectoryIterator выдает тоже самое количество каталогов

Comment: @LANSELOT значит проблема точно в правах

Comment: @LANSELOT Попробуйте набрать в консоли `ls -l | wc -l`, что бы узнать реальное кол-во файлов

Comment: @LANSELOT и еще можете посмотреть, сколько файлов с правами определенного юзера или группы – `ls -l | grep "root" | wc -l` (где `root` надо заменить на своего юзера веб сервера)

Comment: ls -l | wc -l выводит как и положено, ls -l | grep "root" | wc -l тоже

Comment: @LANSELOT странно, не было таких проблем у меня. Тут может помочь наверное сис. админ. Может там что с файловыми дескрипторами или `inode`

Comment: Зачем сисадмин, в консоли же правильно все выводит

Comment: @LANSELOT потому что код отрабатывает корректно, а с доступом что-то не то. Проверьте ещё раз абсолютный путь, права. В консоли вы так же под юзером залогинены, под кем сервер запущен?

Comment: права на обрабатываемый каталог и в него вложенные каталоги стоят 777. Сервер запущен под рутом. На данный запрос апачу позволено 256MB оперативы

Comment: @LANSELOT это конечно все очень плохо, права 777 и запуск апача из под рута. Странно, что не решает проблему. Добавьте код в вопрос, может что прояснится.

Comment: удалил несколько каталогов, выводит то же самое количество. Значит дело не в правах. Какие настройки php могут повлиять на подобные лимиты?

Comment: @LANSELOT интересно, надо смотреть. А что за настройка - "На данный запрос апачу позволено 256MB оперативы"?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33264/discussion-between-korytoff-and-lanselot).

Comment: с чего бы им быстрее-то быть

Comment: Ну мое предположение, потому что  они были написаны позже всего, а во-вторых подгружают данные порционно, в отличии от `scandir()`. В третьих – тестировал. Апрув – [scandir()](http://joxi.ru/L21jK1jHVX3MAX), [yield](http://joxi.ru/p27LnqLiEQbPA7), [DirectoryIterator](http://joxi.ru/GrqebPefy10grz)

Comment: Вы путаете расход оперативки со скоростью. В ваших же примерах генератор работает со скорость скандира, итератор наоборот, выигрывает, но все это настолько мизерно, что можно и забыть о различиях.

Comment: @Etki да, уже обновил ответ. Но если надо обойти миллионы директорий с рекурсией, то думаю выигрыш будет, хоть и небольшой

Answer (score 1):

`scandir` возвращает только файлы/папки, находящиеся по текущему пути. Он не обходит вложенные директории рекурсивно.

Comment: Они все в одном каталоге находятся, рекурсивность не нужна